# Chrome Chonsole and console.log(object)

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

I have Chrome in version 37.
If I try to log some objects with `console.log(object)`, I get a very strange behaviour.

The preview is different from the expanded in the Chrome console.
The preview is correct.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Console]

Answer (score 0):

The expanded view is in alphabetical order

Comment: No, widgets is in preview null but in the expanded view an empty array.

Comment: Ach, sorry dude, missed that